# PUT no longer works after upgrading my server to to Windows Server 2012 / VS 2012 / IIS 8.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, servicestack, iis-8

After upgrading a workstation to Windows Server 2012 / VS 2012 - and re-deploying your existing ServiceStack services to IIS 8, PUTs start returning a 405?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get PUT's to work again in Windows Server 2012 and IIS8 you need to remove WebDav Publishing from IIS.